# Stock Reduction Multiplier For Variations

Tags: magento2, inventory

I have a customer who is looking at moving to Magento, but one of her major barriers is that we have a custom code programmed for Woocommerce to allow the stock to be sold in individual quantities and box quantities using variations.

So for example, she sells a blue glass bottle. You can select a variation of either:

- Individual items (and multiple using the QTY)
- Box Quantity (and multiple using the QTY)

When a customer purchases a box variation (of 32 items) the stock will reduce the product inventory by 32.

The reason it is done this way is that she doesn't hold the stock in pre-packaged boxes. Instead, if she orders a box quantity she will package them up into a bundle of 32 for shipping. So the stock between individual and box variations are from the same pool.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be achieved in Magento? In wordpress, we have a box when adding a variation which is pretty much "Reduce QTY by [ ]" where you can enter "32" so if a box is purchased it reduces the stock by 32.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hope that you can solve this problem using Magento 2 Bundle products.